# CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to make a CSS Selector that matches the following?

```
All OBJECT elements
  which have a PARAM element inside of them
```

The selector

```
OBJECT PARAM
```

doesn't work, as it matches the PARAM, not the OBJECT.  I'd like to apply { display:none } to the objects; it's useless to apply that to the PARAMs.

(I'm aware I could pull this off with jQuery - `$("object param").closest("object")` - and VanillaJS - `document.querySelector("object param").closest("object")` - but I'm trying to create CSS rules on a page.)

Comment: is there css collections selector like this `.main [:hover,ul,ul>li,p] { display:inline-block;}`

Comment: Can do a "has children" selector `object:not(:empty) { display: none; }` http://jsfiddle.net/xeepete/949a55oo/

Comment: @xeepete can you provide a more complete suggestion?

Comment: There is now an answer! The :has selector is being added to CSS. Reopen the question?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

No, what you are looking for would be called a *parent selector*. CSS has none; they have been proposed multiple times but I know of no existing or forthcoming standard including them. You are correct that you would need to use something like jQuery or use additional class annotations to achieve the effect you want.

Here are some similar questions with similar results:

- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/css-parent-selector)
- [CSS Parent/Ancestor Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector)
- [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Comment: JSYK, the CSS parent selector will be coming in CSS4, as the ability to select which element in a selector is styled by putting a dollar sign in front of it: `$div > span` would select the div that has a span as a direct child.

Comment: Put a dollar sign before a selector part, so it could interfere with SCSS/SASS syntax, cool.
Why don't they use the many times proposed `<` sign, or `:parent` pseudo class, or even the `!` sign after a selector part? They all seem more logical to me, than using the `$` sign...

Comment: yea i know, php much

Comment: Why would you say "Select all elements having a descendant" is anything similar to "select a particular ancestor of a given element"? On places context on an element and seeks out descendants. The other places context on an element and seeks our ancestors. They are fundamentally QUITE different.

Comment: @rainabba It doesn't matter which end you start the search on. Both approaches end up selecting the same elements. In that sense, they are equivalent.

Comment: @Mészáros Lajos CSS does not depend on SCSS, they have no obligation to do that. I'd rather see CSS become robust enough to render LESS/SCSS obsolete actually, regardless of which syntax is chosen.

Comment: @Josh Ribakoff - That would be awesome, but I doubt, they want to add that much functionality to CSS.

Comment: there is a parent selector, called :has, it has a limited scope but it should work for the case here. See one of the following answers

Comment: edit : as seen in the possible duplicate page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), it is not available in any browser.

Comment: FYI, this now exists in the CSS Selectors Level 4 spec: [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational)

Comment: For browser support, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

Comment: One year later, still no cigar.

Comment: Two more years later, jQuery is still my friend

Comment: Whaaat.  Good christmas, the use case is bonker-doodle obvious, and this is **still** not implemented?  This has been possible in XPath since, well, maybe the beginning: `//parent[child]` selects any element named `parent` that has an immediate child named `child`.  <...smh...>

Comment: halfway through 2020... still waiting...

Comment: When this answer was posted people had wanted had already wanted it for, like, forever. It seemed like an egregiously long time to wait for such a basic selector. I was 29. 

3/4 of the way though 2021 and still no dice. My phone has more processing power than my dev machine did back then. I'm 41.

Answer (score 112):

Only thing that comes even close is the `:contains` pseudo class in CSS3, but that only selects textual content, not tags or elements, so you're out of luck.

A simpler way to select a parent with specific children in jQuery can be written as (with [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)):

```
$('#parent:has(#child)');
```

Comment: Thanks -- but how is that different from $("#parent #child")?

Comment: `$("#parent #child")` selects all #child elements that are children of #parent. `$('#parent:has(#child)')` selects all #parent elements that have #child as children.

Comment: The OP said that he knew how to do it with jQuery, but wanted CSS

Comment: @SpeedyNinja, nevertheless answer contains better jQuery snippet than topic starter's

Comment: This example doesn't make much sense because IDs have to be unique so you wouldn't select it more generically like this. It'd make more sense if they were classes

Comment: how to do it without jqueezy?

Comment: @ZachSaucier The example makes sense in some cases. The site may have different pages where `#parent` sometimes contains `#child` and sometimes does not. If you only want to do something with the `#parent` element when it has `#child`, then this is a way to accomplish that.

Comment: Browser support is far from perfect: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

Comment: Currently only supported on Safari (Mar '22)

Answer (score -6):

Is there any way you could programatically apply a class to the object?

```
<object class="hasparams">
```

then do

```
object.hasparams
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do this before the objects even exist; otherwise they will flash up momentarily before being hidden.

Comment: If your problem is the flash of unstyled content (FOUC) maybe you should solve this. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221561/need-help-eliminating-flash-of-unstyled-content-on-my-site/9823468#9823468

Comment: Few years late to the party but YES, take a look at tahdhaze09 answer, you would use " object [class ^='hasparams'] "