# Css selector for a > strong

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple Css rule like so:

```
strong a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

This works for the following HTML:

```
<strong>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Go to website</a>
</strong>
```

The problem is the Wysiwyg within the CMS i am using often puts the code in like so:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><strong>Go to website</strong></a>
```

My css rule then doesnt work. Is there are pure Css solution?

Thanks
Al

Comment: Just to make the point clear: you want to hide the underline of links that have a `<strong>` in them. `a:hover strong` **doesn't work** because `<a>` already has the underline. (You should really express that more clearly, that is the heart of your question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
.hrefspan a:hover, strong {
text-decoration: none;}

<span class="hrefspan"><a>...</a></span>
```

By putting it in a span and applying the css only to the content of that span it will not affect other href's or strong's.

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying to do isn't supported in CSS - you can't style the parent. A better approach here might be to add a class to the link:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" class="ImportantLink">Go to website</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.ImportantLink { font-weight:bold; }
a.ImportantLink:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

That way the link can easily be styled. `<strong>` may be semantically wrong if you use it just to style the link, and not to emphasize the text (though, that might be less important, to be honest)

Working Example: **http://jsbin.com/ekuza5**

Comment: Best solution. Exactly what I was whipping up til you did it first! +1

Answer (score 2):

use

```
a:hover strong 
{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't work because `a` will still have an underline. I was wrong too. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

since you have define rule strong a:hover
indicates rules to be applied to the a tag which is present inside strong html tag

Answer (score 0):

So the bit you actually want to change is the underling of the anchor

```
a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
```

If you want to have this only affect particular links on the page then apply classes to them.

```
<a class="notunderlined" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><strong>Foobar</strong></a>

a.notunderlined:hover { text-decoration:none; }
```