# CSS select all li which not contains a tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select all li which not contains a tag in css:

```
ul.sf-menu li:not(a)
```

But looks like it is not working.

Need help

```
<ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
    <li>
        <a href="/ ">
    </li>
    <li> need to select this li because it is not contains a href
        A 
        <ul style="visibility: visible; display: block">
            <li>
                <a href="/B-1">
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/B-2">B-2</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
 <li>
```

Comment: Can't work, because that piece of css matches all <li>s that aren't <a>s

Comment: This question is also a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You don't need a parent selector (which is what you're asking for) here. Though I'm not sure what the answer is, because you've not described your *actual problem* - you've simply asked how to select a certain element.

Comment: css4 supports these sorts of selectors.

Answer (score 7):

Two things

1) Your selector doesn't match the question you're asking.  It currently selects every LI that is **not** an Anchor. This should be every LI on the page.

2) What you want can't be done with CSS right now. Your best bet would be to use some JavaScript to do this.  For instance, the following jQuery would work.

```
$("ul.sf-menu li:not(:has(a))").doSomething()
```