# Selenium WebDriver CSS equivalent to xpath not contains

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

I want to avoid using xpath in my java selenium code but cannot figure out what the css equivalent to the code below would be

("xpath", "//div[@class='error'][not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]");

Does anyone know if there is a CSS equivalent to xpath not contains

Comment: Look there http://stackoverflow.com/a/7473354/1000986

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily match against a compound attribute (*i.e.*, `style=`) in CSS.  The `not` part is easy - CSS3 has a `:not(...)` selector.  You're going to have to find something else to identify the elements you want to exclude, and then use `:not(...)` to exclude them,