# Style a div differently when a specific class exists in a child div / jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, parent

Basically I need div.content to have a default padding of 15px EXCEPT for when the div has the child div.products-list. If the child div of .products-list exists I need div.content to have no padding. I read and saw several solutions using jquery, but it seems to have no effect. My layout is like this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".products-list").parents("div.content").css("padding", "0");
});
</script>

<style>
.content {
padding: 15px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
<div class="products-list"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just checked that in JSFiddle and it works correctly.

Comment: Releated question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2000582/901048

Comment: Perhaps the problem is elsewhere and this is working but you have other problems causing whatever root issue you are trying to solve?? Maybe try turning your default padding up to 150px so you can see really clearly if it is being reset down to nothing. or change the setting of padding to setting of a background-colour so you can test the jquery itself. I agree with richard Banks though that what you have seems to work...

Comment: JSFiddle's solution works beautifully. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a little CSS trickery to "eliminate" the padding by using negative margins on the inner div:

```
div.content {
    padding: 15px;
}
div.products-list {
    margin: -15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2HRUc/

Comment: Awesome! That worked. And such a simple solution too. I was completely over thinking the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if($("div.product-list div.content").length > 0) {
    $("div.product-list").css('padding', 0);
}
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
if($("div.product-list div.content").length > 0) {
    $("div.product-list").css('padding', 0);
}
});

Comment: Your selectors are the wrong way round here (div.content isn't a child of div.product-list). Also this shouldn't behave any differently. Except I would imagine a bit slower since it does the selecting all over again (I assume parents is a relatively quick function compared to a selector search across the whole dom.