# Image tag showing pdf icon when placed inside a tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

We use a `a[href*=".pdf"]` CSS selector rule to show a pdf icon when the href has .pdf as its extension, but the problem is it’s showing for `<a>` tags with image tags inside them as well as well.

```
<a href="foo.pdf">foo</a> => Works fine
<a href="foo.pdf"><img src="big_image.gif" /></a> => No good.
```

We don't want to show the PDF icon for this kind of links.

Please let me what kind of CSS selectors we should write for such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid there isn’t a CSS selector that lets you select links that don’t have `<img>` tags inside them. (See [CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar).)

jQuery lets you select links that *do* contain images via [its `:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/). You could use that to add a class to links with an image inside them, and use that class to turn off your PDF styles.

Otherwise, you’ll need to add a class to these links on the server.