# CSS selector precedence issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an to write a selector similar to:

`div#content > section (.left > img) + .left`

but obviously the parenthesis are ignored. How should I rewrite this? Or it isn't possible in plain CSS?

Comment: Can you elaborate what the result should be?

Comment: Agreed more info is needed or maybe the html markup you are working with

Comment: Well, yes, I have a section in my main content div. I want to style each .left class which is directly preceded by another .left class, which, in turn, has an img child beneath it in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your trying to do is not possible at least not as of the latest css3 spec.

If your not wanting to add via the server, maybe a bit of jQuery?

See this fiddle as it does what you want very easily

http://jsfiddle.net/4qZpc/2/embedded/result/ - results!

Grab the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4qZpc/2/

Comment: Will go for the jQuery solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't select something in CSS based on what it contains, which is essentially what you are attempting in the parentheses.

[It's best explained by this question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)

Comment: So...will have to try another approach. Too bad. Thank you for helping.

Comment: It's an easy selector with JQuery, but not directly possible with CSS, sorry.

Comment: jQuery mootools dojo you name the lib and its uber simple, check out the fiddle I created below to see one jQuery solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

How about giving the section an id (assuming you have multiple sections) and then doing something like:

```
#content-section img + .left
```

I'm not entirely sure what effect you're trying to achieve here, but if there isn't a particular case where a .left element directly follows an img other than here, you should be safe.

Alternatively, if you have nested .left elements, you could do:

```
#content-section img + .inner-left
```

Comment: I wanted not to use additional ids...I hoped it can be resolved only with selectors and existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add server-side an `.image_in_it` class on each element with `.left` class *if* it contains an img element.

```
<div id="content">
    <section>
        <div class="left image_in_it">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="left">
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

and then `div#content > section > .left.image_in_it + .left` would select any `.left` directly following `.left.image_in_it`

Comment: I wanted not to use additional ids...I hoped it can be resolved only with selectors and existing classes. But thank you anyway!