# Is there a way to style only parent elements of nested unordered lists?

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-lists, parent-child

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)
>   [CSS selector for “foo that contains bar”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)

I have a set of nested unordered lists, and I want to be able to style just the `<li>` parent items that have children.  The html look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item three
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li
</ul>
```

I want to be able to add a background image, i.e., to ONLY "item three".  What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use jQuery to loop through the UL and find LI elements with UL children.  Like so maybe?:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .newClass {
        background: #059;
    }
</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainUL li').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('newClass');
        }
    });
});

</script>

<ul id="mainUL">
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item three
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simple, just like I like it.  Thanks, @iDsteven.