# css - define styling for siblings child element

Tags: css

I am trying to define styling for second sibling's child element based of first sibling's class.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve

```
<div >
      <div class="one">
          <div class="find edit">
              Find me
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
          <div class="change">
              Change me
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I want "Change me" to be green if "edit" class is found. Is it possible to achieve this purely based on css?

Help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Medha

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Comment: Also [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1331430)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can find answer:

[Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Short answer copied from link:

> **Selectors are unable to ascend**
>
> CSS offers no way to select a parent or ancestor of element that
>   satisfies certain criteria. A more advanced selector scheme (such as
>   XPath) would enable more sophisticated stylesheets. However, the major
>   reasons for the CSS Working Group rejecting proposals for parent
>   selectors are related to browser performance and incremental rendering
>   issues.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible to access the parent selector (I wish it was). If you could consider this structure, it'll be no problem at all:

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="one edit">
    <div class="find">
      Find me
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="change">
      Change me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.one.edit + .two .change { color: green; }
```

---

If not, you could easily accomplish what you're after with a little JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Now I notice the `edit` class required in the child. You cannot.

simply you need something like a `parent` selector, and this doesn't exist in CSS 3, it's suggested in CSS 4 though, but that's far from happening any time soon.

More here:

[CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar/2000614#2000614)

.

**Original:**

Depending on which browsers you care about, this may work:

```
div.one + div.two > div.change {
    color: green;
}
```

Reference:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Live Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/NVjq6/

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question as he's looking for a selector that depends on the presence of `.edit`

Comment: Yep. Not possible now. The upcoming [subject selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) may make that possible, but as you say, that's still a ways off.