# Hover the background of two elements

Tags: html, css, hover

**This my HTML**:

```
<div id="orange">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            Text stuf and information
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with css when you hover the `h4` that the background change of the `div#orange` to? I know the `h4:hover #...` thing but then you go deeper and deeper.

I don't want when you hover the `div#orange` that the `h4` is changing but only when you hover the `h4` that the background of the `div#orange` is changing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the parent element, when hovering a child element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114657/how-to-style-the-parent-element-when-hovering-a-child-element)

Comment: This topic is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000614/2851870. Based on the links in that answer, this could be possible with CSS4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need, when someone hover in the title the background of the **div orange** change, so that's mean hover in child and change parent element, but there is no CSS selector for selecting a parent of a selected child.

you could do it with JavaScript, here is an example

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="orange">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <h4 id="title">Title</h4>
            Text stuf and information
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.hoverorange {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

**JavaScript CODE**

```
$("#title").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest("#orange").toggleClass("hoverorange")
});
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/greenfox/VABeF/)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible using only css. You could use js to do it.