# Adding a class to element that has a specific descendant

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code generated by Simple Html Dom Parser:

```
<a href='....'>
   <div class='test'>...</div>
</a>
```

How can I add a class to the a element? I presume that I can do this with Jquery?

I only need to add a class to the elements that have a div with class 'test' as descendant.

Comment: Yes, and you can do it in pure JS also :) (What's the event that should add the class?)

Comment: on page load, the purpose of it is that later on I can use css on it, but something comes to mind, can I select the element with pure css?

Comment: No, you cannot target up-the-tree using CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
$('.test').parent().addClass('whatever');
```

Or

```
 $('.test').closest('a').addClass('whatever');
```

The first if you know the `a` element is the parent, the second if you just know the `a` element contains, even multiple levels deep, the `.test` class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parent` method:

```
$('.test').parent().addClass('my-class');
```

Or without jQuery:

```
/* On one element. */
document.querySelector('.test').parentNode.classList.add('my-class') ;
/* On all elements. */
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.test'), function (div) {
    div.parentNode.classList.add('my-class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS, also considering that `.test` can be a further descendant than a child:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(node) {
    if ( node.querySelector('.test') )
        node.classList.add('foo')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add class
    $('.test').parent().addClass('yourClass');

To remove class
    $('.test').parent().removeClass('yourClass');