# css selector of an element having an element in its hierarchy with specific attribute

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<a id="inbox_row_container_24_112" class="inbox_row_container row_even" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <span id="inbox_message_24_112" class="inbox_message">
   <span id="inbox_message_attributes_24_112" class="inbox_message_attributes">
   <span id="inbox_message_attachment_24_112" class="inbox_message_attachment">*</span>
   <span class="inbox_row_clear"></span>
</a>
```

In the above, I want to obtain "inbox_row_container_24_112" if it has element with id="inbox_message_attachment_24_112" in its hierarchy.

Can anyone please suggest how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a parent selector, AKA find $('#inbox_message_attachment_24_112') and go to its parent. Unfortunately, CSS does not have this.

similar question:
[CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)

One of the answers suggests using this in jquery:

```
$('#parent:has(#child)');
```

I would suggest starting there! :)

Comment: using javascript similar to the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you want to use CSS? This is perfect for xpath;

```
//a[@id="inbox_row_container_24_112" and span[@id="inbox_message_attachment_24_112"]]
```

Or if you wanted to lose tag constraints;

```
//*[@id="inbox_row_container_24_112" and *[@id="inbox_message_attachment_24_112"]]
```

Selenium supports Xpath as well as CSS, and you should choose a selector which meets the needs of your situation, and in this case Xpath seems more suitable than CSS

Comment: I agree with you. I am going ahead with javascript for now.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [Helium](http://heliumhq.com) - Selenium WebDriver wrapper which offers a jQuery-like selector as part of its API.

Assuming you are using WebDriver in Java, you can try the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import static com.heliumhq.API.*;

public class MyElementFinder {
    public WebElement findMyElement() {
        startChrome("YOUR-URL-HERE");
        $ inboxMessageAttachment = $("#inbox_row_container_24_112 #inbox_message_attachment_24_112");
        WebElement elem = inboxMessageAttachment.getWebElement();
        do {
            elem = elem.findElement(By.xpath("parent::node()"));
        } while (!elem.getAttribute("id").equals("inbox_row_container_24_112"));
        return elem;
    }
}
```

Please note that your HTML code is not 100% valid - two of the `<span>` tags do not have corresponding closing tags `</span>`. If the HTML code was corrected and looked as following:

```
<a id="inbox_row_container_24_112" class="inbox_row_container row_even" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <span id="inbox_message_24_112" class="inbox_message"></span>
   <span id="inbox_message_attributes_24_112" class="inbox_message_attributes"></span>
   <span id="inbox_message_attachment_24_112" class="inbox_message_attachment">*</span>
   <span class="inbox_row_clear"></span>
</a>
```

Then the Helium script would have been much shorter and nicer:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import static com.heliumhq.API.*;

public class MyElementFinder {
    public WebElement findMyElement() {
        startChrome("YOUR-URL-HERE");
        $ inboxMessageAttachment = $("#inbox_row_container_24_112 > #inbox_message_attachment_24_112");
        return inboxMessageAttachment.getWebElement().findElement(By.xpath("parent::node()"));
    }
}
```

In the both above examples the findMyElement() method throws an exception of type NoSuchElementException if no such element exists - this can be handled to cover the case when there is no such element present.

*Disclaimer*: I'm one of Helium's developers

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the child with CSS:

```
#inbox_row_container_24_112 > #inbox_message_attachment_24_112
```

There is no way to obtain the parent once you selected the child, though.
However, using JavaScript this would be an easy problem to solve.