# Can i select div's containing an inputfield?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if I can select a `div` when it has an `input` field as a child.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<div class="xxx">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">my title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">some content</div>
            <div class="col.md-7">some content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">some content</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap adds a padding and margin to all `div` blocks if they have col-* classes. What I want to achieve is that, if a `div` contains an `input` field, then the margin and padding should be set to 0px.

So the main question is: "Can I select a div according to his content?"

I have tried  `div[class*="..."]` and `div[class^="..."]`, but neither is solving my problem.

Comment: CSS doesn't really have a :has, :contains or parent selector, so me thinks you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose an alternate strategy. You can add a class to those div and use css rule to apply zero padding and margin.

```
<div class="col-md-3 zero-padding-margin">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" />
        </div>
```

And

```
  .zero-padding-margin {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: this is how im dooing it atm. seems like i can't come around using extra classes for this.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector,

```
$('div:has(:input)')
```

Or you can use,

```
$(':input').filter(function(){
  return $(this).parent('div').length;
}).parent();
```

Comment: don't get me wrong.. sorry... i want a selector in css

Comment: @Dwza Then why did you tag this question with jquery.?

Comment: Note that in the posted markup, almost all the DIV's would match this, as they all have an input, being nested and all.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, i too thought of that, now provided an alternate to it.

Comment: @Dwza http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar this would help you

Comment: `$('div > input').closest('div')` seems simpler, I haven't tested it though.

Comment: or `$('div > input').parent()`.

Comment: comon guys what will be the css selector for this?

Comment: i just ready this is not available in the css today, but will be available in the css4.

Comment: I heard it would be one of those in CSS 4 or 5 : `input ^ div, div! input, div:has(input)`

Comment: guys... its nice seeing you discussing my problem. but, i already sayed, i have no problem with jquery and i don't want to use it for this task :)

Comment: @Dwza: Then fix the tag.

Comment: i already did. guess it came back in because someone edited my question at the same time. i still give a +1 for this answere because if i would use jquery for this... this would obviously help :)