# Is it possible for CSS to select both siblings and descendants?

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

Note: I am not asking how to select the parent.

Before I ask my question, here's some quick background.

One can use immediate sibling selectors:

```
p + p { background: red; }
```

... to select the second `<p></p>`:

```
<p></p>
<p>selected!</p>
```

One can use immediate child selectors:

```
p > span {background: red; }
```

... to select only a `span` that is the immediate child of `p`:

```
<p>
  <span></span>
</p>
```

Okay, great.

Now, how does one select only `<p>` elements that immediately follow
`<p>`'s containing only a `<br>`?

```
<p>            <!-- when there is a p                     -->
  <br />       <!-- and it only contains a br             -->
</p>
<p>            <!-- select the p immediately following it -->
   Select me! 
</p>
```

I tried `p > br:only-child + p {background: red;}` but this is not quite right.

Comment: It won't work, since it would involve reaching the child and going back to the parent... And parent travelling is something css selectors can't do

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you would need some javascript to do this, at which point it might be too much overhead, depends on your implementation.

Comment: Are you okay for a JS solution as well?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar

Comment: @LcSalazar & Jordan You both answered my question fully. Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: You may not be asking how to select the parent, but you are looking to match an element based on its nature as a parent of another element, which is the same principle. Consequently, you're not asking to "select both the sibling and the descendant", but you're looking to express a complex relationship that involves both. The simple answer is that this cannot be expressed using what is currently offered in selector syntax.

Comment: It's sad that we can write `p:empty + p` but not `p:contains(br) + p`. The former checks descendants and siblings just like the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely impossible.

You cannot select a parent element based on its children.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you would need some javascript to do this, at which point it might be too much overhead, depends on your implementation.

Comment: Woops, I thought that's what I clicked, my bad