# CSS selector for td's with img inside

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select all td's with a image inside?

`td img {}` selects all images inside a td, but may I go the other way?

Comment: There's no parent selector.

Comment: No, Css can only go in the descendant way

Comment: You should consider using some javascript to do what you need.

Comment: there can be multiple ways one can achieve as suggested above, and it would be good if you post your code along, it would help you to get some good suggestion and advices

Comment: Css doesn't support parent selectors as mentionned here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar

Instead using Javascript with Jquery it can be as simple as :

https://jsfiddle.net/pgd0noew/