# (LESS/CSS), Trying to modify a property of an outer element based on whether an inner element contains a particular class

Tags: css, angularjs, less, parent-child

I have a modal window with a bootstrap `modal-content` class, where I need to change the background color to transparent for a particular modal. Because this has been set up for me, I can't actually add classes to the `modal-content` `div`.

I only want to change this property if the `div` within this contains the class `erm-modal`. Currently my Less file looks like this:

```
modal-content {
  background-color: transparent;
  .erm-modal {
     ......
  }
}
```

This changes my background color correctly, but also changes the background color for all the other modals as well! Can I write some less to allow me to only change this property if the child `div` contains `.erm-modal`?

I am using AngularJS if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can not style the parent in any way from the perspective of a child's selector (by now its simply impossible in CSS and thus in Less too). So you'll have to rethink your HTML/CSS structure.

Comment: Agree with @seven-phases-max' comment. You would either have to rethink the markup/structure (or) use Javascript. I am not recommending the use of jQuery but if you are already using it then try the `:has()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)