# target div inside nav on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu on hover i show different background color for `li` which has div present with class `dropdown` and different color for `li` which dont have sub menu wrapped inside div

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>
   <a href="page1"> page one</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="page2"> page one</a>
   <div class="dropdown"> .....</div>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="page3"> page one</a>
</li>
<ul>
```

I want to target  only `li` which don't have any sub menu or in other words div present with class `class="dropdown"`.

I know this can be achieved using jquery using `hasClass` but i want to do this using css only.

Comment: It is not possible by pure css.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't target elements that contain certain child elements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000614/543224

Comment: css lacks a parent selector so you're not gonna make it with css only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate style and scripting, your best bet is to check for the dropdown class with jQuery and add a class to its parent (e.g. contains_dropdown). Give that class contains_dropdown the style you want.