# Targeting the text in an anchor element but not the image

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I do not want the picture to be underlined, but I need the hyperlink in the text to be underlined. How can I do that? It is a wordpress theme so I can't change the html I have to stay with css

```css
.post-desc a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FBCF00;
}
.post-desc a img{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-desc">
<a href="http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/exterieur-1.jpg" target="_blank" rel="attachment wp-att-2763"><img class="alignnone wp-image-2763 size-full" src="http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/exterieur-1.jpg" alt="extérieur de Tod condo" width="639" height="438"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: here is the full site to see the probleme: http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/tod-condo-a-boisfranc/

Comment: I don't see any text in your anchor tag? What exactly do you want to underline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it under the image using `display:table;` on image, like this:

```
.post-desc a img{
    border-bottom: none;
    display:table;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.post-desc a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FBCF00;
}
.post-desc a img {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-desc">
  <a href="http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/exterieur-1.jpg" target="_blank" rel="attachment wp-att-2763">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-2763 size-full" src="http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/exterieur-1.jpg" alt="extérieur de Tod condo" width="639" height="438">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to make it simple you may use `vertical-align` with a negative value to drop `img` as much as needed under the base line:

```css
a {
  border-bottom: solid;
}
a img {
  vertical-align: -0.5em;/* average -0.25em equals vertical-align:bottom */
 /* demo purpose: see border under img */
 opacity:0.75;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">text</a>
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60" />
</a>
```

within the last stylesheet of your website , test this

```
a img {
  margin-top:0.5em;
  vertical-align:  -0.5em;
}
```

or if you like better:

```
a img {
  position:relative;
  top: 0.5em;
}
```

The idea is to hide the border with the image itself

Answer (score 0):

Text decoration underline

```
<div><a style="text-decoration:underline" href="http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/exterieur-1.jpg" target="_blank" rel="attachment wp-att-2763"><img class="alignnone wp-image-2763 size-full" src="http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/exterieur-1.jpg" alt="extérieur de Tod condo" width="639" height="438"></a>
```

Comment: I want to use : border-bottom: 1px solid #FBCF00; for the color but it need to be remove under the image

Answer (score 0):

You have set the border attributes on the `<a>` tags, so you can't just remove them on the containing `<img>` elements. Unfortunately, there is no ["conatining" selector in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar) (yet) and apparently you can't edit the html, so we have to stick with the informations we've got.

The links with the containing images have the word `attachment` in the attribute `rel`. This is how to select them and disable their border:

```
a[rel~="attachment"] {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```