# Implementing a parent selector in CSS with jQuery that applies automatically to new elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent

CSS does not support parent selectors, e.g. "select all `<p>` that contain an `<img>`".

One solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is to use jQuery, for example:

`$('#parent:has(#child)').addClass('my-special-class');`

However, I have a `<div>` that is periodically updated with new content, and I need to keep reapplying the `my-special-class` to new elements that match the selector `'#parent:has(#child)'` inside that `<div>`.

How could one do that?

I am styling a third-party plugin so I don't have much control over its styling, events and so on.

Comment: Why don’t use css class for parent that has direct children your desired parent that contains the img? I mean .wrapper > .parentIMG

Comment: This isn't an issue with the parent selector but due to the nature of jQuery selections not being live in general. That is, you'll run into this problem regardless of what selector you use.

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez I don't see how this can be done. Let's say you have two `<p>` elements: `div > p > img` and `div > p > span`. How do you style the first `p` but not the second `p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to bind the `DOMSubtreeModified` event on the container div and add your code inside.

```
$('.container').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $('.parent:has(.child)').addClass('special-child');
});
```

```js
// find elements
var parent = $("#parent")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  const el = '<div class="parent"><p class="child">Hello World</p></div>';
  parent.after(el);
})

$(function() {
  $('.parent:has(.child)').addClass('special-child');

  $('.continer').on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    $('.parent:has(.child)').addClass('special-child');
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.child {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 4px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.special-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="continer">
  <div class="parent" id="parent">
    <p class="child">Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Add Child</button>
```

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` has been deprecated in favor of the Mutation Observer API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: Using DOMSubtreeModified leads to an infinite loop in Internet Explorer after the second call. Other browsers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following jquery and just one class, it will work like `:visited`:

```
$("div.my-div").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("visited");
});
```

And just add one class to the css:

```
.visited:hover{
  outline: 2px solid orange;
}
```

If you add this code with the current code of yours, you will get the same functionality as the one for `:visited`.

Here is a fiddle that I tried on your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/27srmuy6/