# Can I use CSS3 Selectors to select based on a child element?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need to select a `<p>` element that has a nested `<a>` with a specific class.

The `<a>` is not always a child of the `<p>` and may instead be a grandchild. For example:

```
<p>some text<span><a href="#" class="myclass f5">link</a></span></p>
```

I need to select the `<p>` element if it has an `<a>` with the class `f5` anywhere inside.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this isn't possible with a css selector ([theres nothing like a parent-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)).

maybe you can work around this with javascript - in jquery, for example, you should get your paragraphs with `$('p:has(a.f5)')` (and then you're free to `.addClass()` or set `.css()` on this elements directly).

**EDIT:**:
you might also want to take a look at this other questions on SO (and next time: [search before you ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#searching)):

- [CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)
- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)
- [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)
- [CSS Parent/Ancestor Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector)