# selecting <label> but excluding <label> that contain <input>

Tags: css

I have 2 types of labels, normal labels like the first line, and labels that contain a input field within them. What CSS rule can let me select all `<label>` but exclude all labels that happen to contain `<input>` within?

```
<label for="type">Some Label</label>

<label for="type">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="type">Some Label
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way of doing this woult be adding different classes to them or at least to one of them.

CSS hasn't a parent selector, so you can't check for an element that contains other withour some javascript.

Some background:
[CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/css-parent-selector)
[CSS Parent/Ancestor Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector)
[Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Comment: Yeah. As I've said, you don't have to create a second class. You can create 1 class and apply it to the lable without the input.

Answer (score 2):

The "adjacent sibling" selector should work, **IF** you are looking for label+input pairs:

```
label+input
{
    /* rules */
}
```

This would ignore your label-nested inputs, unless there happens to be an input after a label that has an input within it.

See Sitepoint's CSS reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

Comment: @sameold The problem with this it that its not IE6 and 7 compatible. If this is not a problem for you, you can define the styles for all lables and overide the ones next (right after or right before, not wrapping) to a input.

Comment: @rcdmk Ah, true. I've developed a bit of a bad habit of forgetting about those two... good catch.