# CSS: selecting an element only if it contains a specific element

Tags: css, printing, css-selectors

I am creating a *print* stylesheet and would like to hide all `figure` tags only if that tag contains an `iframe`, which happen to be embedded YouTube videos. If the `figure` tag contains anything else (i.e. an `img`), I want the tag and its contents to still be shown on the printed page.

I know that I could simply apply a `class` of "video", for example, to my `figure` tag where appropriate, but I want to see if there is a way to accomplish this *via CSS* without resorting to adding classes throughout my site. Also, even though I know they exist, I am not looking for a jQuery solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually CSS4 gives you a parent selector.

Comment: I'm assuming simply hiding the iframe wouldn't suffice?

Comment: Praveen >> I don't believe the browser support is high enough yet for that to be a viable solution at this point.

Comment: Shmiddty>> I had tried just hiding the iframe, but soon came to realize that I also needed the associated figcaption to also be hidden. I was able accomplish that with iframe ~ figcaption, but then was left with a figure tag that created an empty area on my printed sheet due to attributed margins and padding. Alas, that is why I would like to see the entire figure be hidden instead of just its individual contents. (I have edited my original post to hopefully make that more clear.)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: No it doesn't.

Comment: @CanuckInSC: It's literally zero.

Comment: @BoltClock http://davidwalsh.name/css4-preview see the first one! Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it's just not called a "parent selector".

Answer (score 0):

#### You are looking for a parent selector

CSS3 has none, but CSS4 has one that is like selecting using `$`.

#### Here are some similar questions with similar results:

- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/css-parent-selector)
- [CSS Parent/Ancestor Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector)
- [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Comment: FYI, the `$` syntax is already dropped. Nobody knows what the syntax is going to be eventually.

Comment: Okay. Lets see... Something is there for the CSS 4 then... :D Waiting... :D