# What is the alternative to CSS-selecting an ancestor

Tags: css, css-selectors

CSS(3) has descendent selectors, e.g. `td em {color: red};`, but [no ancestor selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector), apparently.

So, what should I do instead of something like `td {border: 1pt solid red} em;` ? i.e., how can I set a style on ancestors of some (X)HTML element?

**Note:**

- Javascript is not relevant for the workaround, something XPath'y might be.

Comment: As I understand your example, if a `td` contains an `em` then you want to set a `border` on it. That is not possible through css alone. Are you open to a javascript/JQuery solution in your "workaround" (as you tagged)? If so, then there is a solution.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for CSS4 selectors to be implemented, then do

```
td! em {
    border: 1pt solid red;
}
```

See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/.

Or...

```
var xpathresult = document.evaluate("//td[.//em]", 
    document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 
while (e=xpathresult.iterateNext()){
    e.classList.add("border");
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.evaluate. Normal browser support caveats apply.

Comment: The element with the exclamantion mark `td` is the element that the rule applies to, instead of the element to the far right of the selector `em` . Just don't hold your breath for support :)